# How to explain realms without magic?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, religion

Multiples realms are a feature in many religious system both fictional and real, they are what allow the gods to seemingly appear out of nowhere and explain how hero move across time and space, think midgar in Thor or Heaven in Christianity, neither of these are physical places in our universe but instead their own realm. How can they be explained them without using magic?

Comment: I don't know much about physics, but my understanding is that there might be multiple "realms" in reality. There are all sorts of different theories explaining how it might be possible. Granted, it seems to be highly speculative and a lot of experts think it's nonsense, but it can definitely be done without invoking magic. Some people think that there are other universes within black holes and subatomic particles and whatever.

Comment: @MilkfromMamaMayor Turn those theories into an answer, I would love to hear them, remember theories are just that; theories, until proven true.

Comment: Well the thing is, I'm not sure it's something that can be proven. If there are other universes, there's no known way to detect or interact with them. People seem to infer their existence based on quantum whozits and whatsits. Again, I know almost nothing about physics. But I'd start by looking up string theory since that seems to be the main reason some believe there must be other universes

Comment: @MilkfromMamaMayor It doesn't need to prove that they exist just explain how they **could** exist

Comment: Um, I think you need to define what you mean by "realms". Listing two examples (both of which can be interpreted in several ways) isn't really descriptive enough.

Comment: Please don't confuse a theory with a hypothesis. In scientific parlace, simplifying a bit, a theory is a hypothesis that is the best fit for available data. It's called the *theory* of general relativity not because it's unproven (we have performed experiments confirming predictions made using the theoretical framework), but rather because it's only the best we have so far; there's no reason to expect that we won't ever come up with something better.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I guess I see your point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are any number of scientific explanations.  Here's one.

Consider a piece of paper.  Let the paper represent part of a two-dimensional plane (pretend it has no thickness).  If you travel in the universe, a corner is as far from the opposite corner diagonally as anything in that portion of that universe.  Now take the paper and fold it so that the two corners are adjacent to each other.  Now if you move in the three-dimensional universe containing that two-dimensional universe, you can move directly from one spot to the other.  From the viewpoint of someone in the two-dimensional universe, you have teleported.

Now think of many two-dimensional universes.  Because they have no thickness, you can move through an infinite number of them with only a finite motion.  So if you can move in three dimensions, you can travel between two-dimensional universes that are adjacent.

How does this help you?  We live in a three-dimensional universe, four including time.  What if our universe is part of a five-dimensional universe?  Then beings that can move in a fourth physical dimension could move from our universe to a different one.  Or from a location in our universe to another that is folded close in the five-dimensional universe.  And note that we aren't limited to five dimensions.  Perhaps there are seventeen dimensions, of which we only use four.  That leaves a lot of room for movement that we do not use.

Someone might only be able to move between points that happen to be close.  Or perhaps there are ways to adjust the hyperdimensional folding in the same way that we can change the way that a paper is folded.

Comment: Reminds me of the answer to Anatomically Correct Gods, that was a good answer to.

Answer (score 2):

"Magic" can be thought of as different physics.

There is an assumption that the rules of physics are the same everywhere in the universe. This is backed up with many astronomical observations, but it's not set in stone. One explanation for "magic" is that this assumption does not hold true, different places in the universe have different physics.

The trouble with this is as soon as a supernatural being moves into our neighborhood they'll have to obey our physics. This could mean they lose their "magic", or it could mean they gain super powers! For example, Superman could be perfectly normal on Krypton under Kryptonian physics, but when he's in our corner of the universe his physical body gives him super powers. Those powers would still have to obey our physics.

Another explanation is that "gods" are trans-dimensional beings, perhaps living in more than 3 physical dimensions, perhaps able to move through time as if it were physical. Their special powers are a result of being able to move in additional dimensions, we only see a 3D slice. For more about this idea, read *[Flatland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatland)*.

A related idea is "gods" are outside our universe looking in. Since they're not in our universe they don't have to obey our laws. They can manipulate the universe like a programmer manipulates a program.

If a god wants to interact with our realm they can build an avatar. This avatar has to obey our laws of physics, but the god doesn't have to when building it. This might allow them to create things which are physically stable, but would normally be impossible to build. Like being able to build a building without scaffolding. They could hollow out a solid sphere from the inside. They could generate any element they wanted, and build with them particle by particle using as much energy to bind them together as they like. So long as the final form holds together under our laws of physics. There is a good example of this at the end of [Permutation City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_City) where (**serious spoilers**, it's a very good book)...

> ...people create a universe with its own different, but internally consistent, physics. Unlike our own, this universe has a well defined edge and we can only interact with it at that edge. Particle by particle, they build a spaceship at the edge along with bodies for themselves to inhabit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if explaining them without magic is possible but you could explain them with scientific Magic ( let me explain I say that without magic it is impossible because typically advanced technology that is indistinguishable from Magic, is Magic, at least in my opinion, if it looks like a duck talks like a duck quacks like a duck it's a duck)

First the idea of other realms or dimensions is not just a religious concept, science have speculated that other dimensions exist for quite some time.

Simply say that your gods crossover from their Dimension to ours using a machine( that is in no way Magic) that creates a bridge or a tunnel through the dimensional barriers allowing allowing your gods to cross over into our world. It's really not that complicated.